# Identify Google Analytics site search categories

Tags: google-analytics, search

My search returns results at the following URLs:

(for a single search term)

```
search/keyword/
```

(for a filtered search using the same term)

```
search/?sections=articles&keywords=keyword
```

In GA, I have:

- Query parameter = search/
- Category parameter = sections, keywords

However in the reports the site search category is coming back as '(not set)' even after a fortnight of use.

Answer (score 1):

GA site search requires a query parameter in your URLs to base site search requests off of, for example `search?keyword=mySearchTerm`. In this example you would enter 'keyword' into the site search configuration.

If your search results page doesn't have a query parameter, then you may need modify your page URL to include it. More information can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en).

Comment: Seemingly GA is happy with 'search/' as a query parameter because it's giving me realistic stats on visits with/without search. It just can't seem to figure out the category parameters I'm supplying.

Comment: Are you able to see your search terms show in the Site Search reports?

Comment: Yes - to get around the permalink not being a true query parameter, there's a filter on the view. It looks for Request URI '/search/(.*)/' and maps the (.*) to a search term. Perhaps the only way is to remove this and adopt MagicDude4Eva's JS-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use GA to provide a virtual path when your search is executed:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/search?query=mysearchterms&category=mycategory');
```

Just make sure that the search terms/category are both URL encoded. You can then use those params in the setup of the site-search.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the point that @MagicDude4Eva made, you can follow [this](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/fix-ga-site-search-google-tag-manager/) guide (particularly section 1) in order to get the site search metrics working fine based on your current URL structure. It requires `Google Tag Manager` to work however you could use the same JavaScript to do this manually if you have code access to the site.

The reason you are getting sessions with / without search data is due to the fact that GA recognizes based on your setup that something was searched, however without a URL parameter it cannot see what was searched. Therefore it'll count a search session but no categorization.